# parallelise prediction with `map_partitions`

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I have a dataframe of shape (25M, 79) and im trying to parallelise an sklearn pipeline prediction on it.

When I run it for just one partition, it works as expected:

```
n_partitions = 1000
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df_x_selection, npartitions=n_partitions)
grid_searcher.best_estimator_.predict_proba(ddf.get_partition(0))
```

But if I apply it to every partition, then it fails:

```
n_partitions = 1000
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df_x_selection, npartitions=n_partitions)

def _f(_df, _pipeline, _predicted_class) -> np.array:
    return _pipeline.predict_proba(_df)[:, _predicted_class]

ddf.map_partitions(_f, grid_searcher.best_estimator_, 1, meta=(None, 'f8')).compute()
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    130             raise ValueError(
--> 131                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
    132                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 79, placement implies 100
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The classifier step of the pipeline is a Lightgbm model (i know -now-, it only supports one process to exec the predict function) but how does that generate the error above?

Comment: Could you please share an [MRCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can reproduce this error?
A couple of sidenotes, which lightgbm model are you using? Some can be parallelized using joblib by setting the `n_jobs=-1` parameter; [Dask-ML can also help parallelize a few](https://ml.dask.org/xgboost.html)